# WPF: KeyboardNavigationMode.Contained doesn't work to suppress focus wrap

Tags: c#, wpf, navigation, focus

I want to navigate in my window with the arrow key. It works so far but if I reach the end of my window, focus wraps to the first main menu item. But I want that focus stops at the last control in my window.

```
private void Window_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Key == Key.Down)
   {
     elem.MoveFocus(FocusNavigationDirection.Next);
   }
}
```

"elem" is indirect child control of "stackPanel". MoveFocus always returns true and I already tried:
    KeyboardNavigation.SetTabNavigation(stackPanel, KeyboardNavigationMode.Contained);       KeyboardNavigation.SetDirectionalNavigation(stackPanel,KeyboardNavigationMode.Contained);
    KeyboardNavigation.SetControlTabNavigation(stackPanel, KeyboardNavigationMode.Contained);

Nothing helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using a [TraversalRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.traversalrequest.aspx) instance?

```
if (e.Key == Key.Down)
{
    e.Handled = true;
    elem.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest 
    { 
        FocusNavigationDirection = FocusNavigationDirection.Next,
        Wrapped = false
    });
}
```

Mind you, the [MSDN documentation for TraversalRequest.Wrapped](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.traversalrequest.wrapped.aspx) says that it's false by default, so the focus shouldn't wrap anyway.

Comment: I now tried this but it didn't not work. After traversing all my controls it continues with the mainmenu items from my mainwindow.